# Retrieve specific value from firebase link?

Tags: android, database, firebase, android-studio

I want to read the value of a link to it in Android Studio with Firebase Databse.

How can I get the value of a specific link as you can see at the image ?[image]

I want to Print out the Value of Vorname. That is Marek!

HOw can I do it?

Comment: Please add entire database structure.

Answer (score 0):

#### As described in [Read and Write Data in the Firebase Real-database documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

If this is the default database for the app:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
```

If this is a secondary database:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://testapp-1234.firebaseio.com");
```

Then get a reference to the database root:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Tausch");
```

Now chain-call the child method on the data base reference until the child you want to read the data from.

```
myRef.child(child_1).child(child_2).child(child_3).getReference("Vorname");
```

Last, read the data using the following:

```
myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // This method is called once with the initial value and again
        // whenever data at this location is updated.
        String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
        // Failed to read value
        Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
    }
});
```